# Load testing a website with iframes using Jmeter

Tags: iframe, jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

I have created a test plan using Jmeter for a process that runs in my UAT environment. A part of the user journey involves hitting a page with an iframe to submit payment using a payment provider.

The payment provider from the iframe has following stages:

1. Enter payment details (Card number, expiry and CVV) and submit
2. User is then taken to another iframe page which shows the payment details summary
3. User then clicks on payment button and payment is submitted and an order ID is generated

How do I implement these iframe requests using JMeter? As part of my solution exploration I have recorded the E2E flow using [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) but surprisingly it does not capture any of the iframe pages relating to the payment process.

Is it even possible to do this using JMeter or should I explore some other possible tool or solution?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

You may have thousands of [iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) but if they don't generate a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - nothing will be recorded.

If you do believe that "blazemeter" (whatever you mean by that) is not capturing the requests which it should be capturing - you can reach out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket).

In the meantime you can try recording the "E2E flow" (whatever you mean by that) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), in this case you will have more or less full control and we'll be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I have concluded that iframes cannot be load tested using JMeter and I agree with you about iframes not generating HTTP requests.

Comment: Actually it's possible using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework. You can install WebDriver Sampler and keep it up-to-date (as well as many other plugins) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)